# How to return an ID of a 'product' after jQuery .autocomplete gets it by name? (Codeigniter, jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form that registers a 'property' to a chosen 'product'.

When typing the products' name - it gets it from the database using the controller, sends it to the model and gets back an array of variables.

Since jQuery 'autocomplete' works with jsons, so it echos the variables as jsons.

I am trying to get the id using a hidden form but without any success, what is the best way doing this?

Model:

```
public function search_prod_name($prod_name){

    $this->db->query(" SELECT prod_name, prod_id FROM prods WHERE prod_name LIKE $prod_name");
    return $this->db->get('prods')->result();

}
```

Controller:

```
// Autocomplete prod name from DB. 
public function search_prod_name(){

    if ( isset($_GET['prod_name']) ){

        $prod_name = $_GET['prod_name'];

        $result = $this->kas_model->search_prod_name();

        if (count($result) > 0){

            foreach ($result as $prod) {

                $arr_name[] = $prod->name; 
                $arr_id[]   = $prod->id;

            }

            echo json_encode($arr_name);
            echo json_encode($arr_id);
        }
    }
}
```

header (jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#prod_name').autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo site_url('kas/search_prod_name'); ?>"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form:

```
<?php 

    // Give a class and ID to the 'prop_prod' autofill
    $attributes = array('class' => 'prod_name', 'id' => 'prod_name', 'name' => 'prod_name');
    $attributes2 = array('name' => 'prop_prod' );
?>

<div class="content kas_reg prop_reg">

<h1>Register a new property:</h1>

    <?php 

        echo form_open('kas/add_property');

        echo form_input('prop_word', 'property');   
        echo form_input('prod_name',  'prod Name', $attributes);    
        echo form_hidden($attributes2);
    ?>


    <select id="country" name="prop_country">
        <!-- options.. -->
    </select>


    <?php

        echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit a New property');

        echo form_close();

    ?>


</div>
```

I'm currently getting the names from the database, but I want to get the ID of this name. so when submitting this - I submit the ID and not the name.

EDIT:

I do have these file and I know for sure that the head is calling them. 
can this be a cache issue maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value and label index in the array find the definition in autocomplete api page

**Controller:**

```
// Autocomplete prod name from DB. 
public function search_prod_name(){

    $data = array();
    $prod_name = $this->input->get('term');

    if ( !empty($prod_name) ){    

        $result = $this->kas_model->search_prod_name($prod_name);

        if (count($result) > 0){

            foreach ($result as $prod) {
                $aRow = array();
                $aRow['label'] = $prod->name; 
                $aRow['value'] = $prod->name; 
                $aRow['id'] = $prod->id; 
                $data[] = $aRow;
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**Model Code**

```
public function search_prod_name($prod_name){

    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT prod_name, prod_id FROM prods WHERE prod_name LIKE '%$prod_name%'");
    return $result->result();

}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#place_name').autocomplete({
        //minLength:2,
        source:function(request, response) {
            var sUrl = "<?php echo site_url('kas/search_prod_name'); ?>";
            $.getJSON(sUrl, request, function(result) {
                response(result);
            });
        },
        select:function(event, ui) {       
          alert('Your selected id is '+ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this during the day :)

Comment: it's very simple one

Comment: `$_GET['prod_name']` you should use this as `$this->input->get('term')` check the updated answer your model function error is fixed

Comment: `#place_name` or you can give your form field name

Comment: It's sltill auto-completing the texts from the data base, but I don't understand why it's giving me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`. for some reason I think its from the `select:` because I don't understand how it gets the results and in what structure, where can I console log?

Comment: oh, it's ajax, i cant console.log :'(

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#prod_name").autocomplete({

  source: function(request, response) {
   var sUrl = "<?php echo site_url('kas/search_prod_name'); ?>";
   $.getJSON(sUrl, request, function(result){
    response(result);
   });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
          alert('Your selected id is '+ui.item.id);
        }

 });

Comment: I thought you having the plugins already. now i updated the libraries check it again

Comment: I do have them, I edited my main post with a print screen.

Comment: I cleared cache, and no changes. 
any idea if using firefox browser can make any problems?

Comment: check your firebug console the request should fire or you have error in firebug console window all tab

Comment: I decided doing this without the ui because I don't really need this in all my code. Can you please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338534/how-to-use-ajax-and-the-html-structure-to-echo-autocomplete-options

Comment: use jquery 1..12 version and see.This should work you may be missed something on your ui i guess.. check you firebug net panel. Before typing inputs on your text box clear the entries and type your text watch that. Check your codeigniter error log files and apache error log files too

Comment: can this be because of `$(document).ready(function(){` in the begginning of my code?

Comment: That you can keep it anywhere if you can show your code i'll resolve that